# JMeter page response is not complete or empty, what to do?

Tags: jmeter, response

I'm running my JMeter scripts for only 5 virtual users. The scenario is: each user logs in to a system using credentials, checks some boxes and clicks the submit button. For the first 4 users, it works fine.  I could see the successful submit button response. But often time for the last user, it seems the response page is not complete, though there's no errors.

Can anyone please tell me how can I ensure a complete page response? I'm attaching a screenshot if that helps.

Thanks!
--Ishti

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the listener on the thread where the request is sent, you might find the thread has been terminated before the response has been consumed.

You have another results tree listener at global scope, does it show the response?

Check jmeter.log to determine the time the thread ended.

Try adding a post-processor to force the thread to wait for response.

Comment: CharlieS, thank you very much for your reply. I didn't get a chance to work on it, had to take some time off from work. I'll check and get back to you ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: CharlieS, the result tree listener at global scope didn't show the response. Could you please elaborate the use of the post-processor with an example? BTW, I cannot re-create the problem anymore. It sometimes comes.

Comment: @IshtiaqueHussain, any post-processor added to the element will have to wait for a response. Or try adding XML Assertion. If the tree listener at global scope did not contain the response then we have to question whether it was sent by the server and received by the client. What do you see if you click on the sampler result tab for the last sample? Does it have a good response code? Or any error, etc?